# compare rows of a column in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below and the logic here is that for each distinct v1 and v2 where v2 is in increasing order v3 must always increase.

```
 v1      v2    v3  
 ABC     0-10   3  
 ABC    10-20   2  
 ABC    20-30   4    
 DEF    10-20  2.5   
 DEF    20-30  3  
 DEF    30-40  1.1  
 DEF    40-50  2.7  
 XYZ    30-40  2
 XYZ    40-50  2  
 XYZ    >50    1
```

if v3 doesnt increase the row is to be deleted resulting in the output as 
 below.

```
 v1      v2    v3  
 ABC     0-10   3   
 ABC    20-30   4    
 DEF    10-20  2.5   
 DEF    20-30  3   
 XYZ    40-50  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the `v3` value in each `v1` group is greater than the `cummax` (cumulative maximum) up until the previous value within that group:

```
dat[ave(dat$v3, dat$v1, FUN=function(x) x - c(-Inf, head(cummax(x),-1))) > 0,]

#   v1    v2  v3
#1 ABC  0-10 3.0
#3 ABC 20-30 4.0
#4 DEF 10-20 2.5
#5 DEF 20-30 3.0
#8 XYZ 40-50 2.0
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text=" v1      v2    v3  
ABC     0-10   3  
ABC    10-20   2  
ABC    20-30   4    
DEF    10-20  2.5   
DEF    20-30  3  
DEF    30-40  1.1  
DEF    40-50  2.7  
XYZ    40-50  2  
XYZ    >50   1", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: @thelatemail, will be grateful to you if you could add explanation too in your code.

Comment: the data frame is sorted already by v2 , 

@thelatemail the soultion doesnt work for a use case where v3  has equal numbers

Comment: @dagan - okely, I have edited to fix this case. I think it works now.